# div container pushed 6th element in the next row

Tags: html, css

I want to create a div container, that contains 6 images. Here is an image:

[image]

Inside this container should be more then 6 images, so I used the `:nth-child()` selector in css. My problem is, that the 6th image is pushed in the next row, and I dont know why.

Here is the code:

```css
*{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

div{
  width: 750px;
  background-color: grey;
}

div > a{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  max-height: 120px;
  max-width: 120px;
  margin-right: 6px;
}

div > a:nth-child(6n){
  margin-right: 6px;
}

div > a > img{
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  max-height: 120px;
  max-width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/120/120/"/>
  </a>
  <a>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/120/120/"/>
  </a>
  <a>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/120/120/"/>
  </a>
  <a>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/120/120/"/>
  </a>
  <a>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/120/120/"/>
  </a>
  <a>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/120/120/"/>
  </a>
</div>
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g2dzgnna/2/)

Answer (score 2):

It is the white space margin issue + your CSS rule `div > a:nth-child(6n)`

Src: https://davidwalsh.name/remove-whitespace-inline-block

*Also using `div > a:last-child` would let you have any number of items and always target the last.*

```css
*{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

div{
  width: 750px;
  background-color: grey;
}

div > a {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  max-height: 120px;
  max-width: 120px;
  margin-right: 6px;
}

div > a:last-child {
  margin-right: 0px;
}

div > a > img{
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  max-height: 120px;
  max-width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/120/120/"/>
  </a><a>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/120/120/"/>
  </a><a>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/120/120/"/>
  </a><a>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/120/120/"/>
  </a><a>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/120/120/"/>
  </a><a>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/120/120/"/>
  </a>
</div>
```

`flex` would be a recommended way to solve it with today, as all major/newer browsers support it.

```css
*{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

div{
  width: 750px;
  background-color: grey;
  display: flex;
}

div > a {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  max-height: 120px;
  max-width: 120px;
  margin-right: 6px;
}

div > a:last-child {
  margin-right: 0px;
}

div > a > img{
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  max-height: 120px;
  max-width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/120/120/"/>
  </a>
  <a>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/120/120/"/>
  </a>
  <a>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/120/120/"/>
  </a>
  <a>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/120/120/"/>
  </a>
  <a>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/120/120/"/>
  </a>
  <a>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/120/120/"/>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! And I thought it's a problem with my css code.

Answer (score 0):

Please change the div width as below:

```
div {
    background-color: grey;
    width: 782px;
}
```